# Converting Binary Response to URL

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm managing an pass-through website and recently the main website we were referencing changed their behavior.  We used to send a `request.post` with form data and get back a public URL to a file.  The new behavior is the response from `request.post` is the binary of the file.

Due to how the pass-through site works, it used to take the URL and save it in a queue and download them one at a time via client side code `$('#download_url').get(0).click()` to emulate a click on the link previously returned from `request.post`.

I'm looking for a simple solution to take the binary response and possibly turn it into a URL so there is minimal change to the rest of the server and client code or sending it directly to the browser is an option at this point too.